# Bracha on Chulent with barley?

Tags: blessing

Which Bracha do you make on chulent that consists of mostly beans with a little bit of barley inside?

Please cite your sources.

Comment: Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6213/759

Comment: I've always heard mezonos, although I would assume shehakol. My schalet uses a 2:1 of barley to beans, although I also use farro.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I'm not sure *shehakol* would apply to the beans. They are pretty clearly recognizable as beans. Most of the "mush* in typical cholent comes from the barley and meat fat / gravy.

Comment: @DanF, true, although I don't even have to think about it, as I eat my schalet after bread.

Answer (score 1):

See this article from [Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/607/cholent-a-guide-to-proper-enjoyment/#_ftn40)

> The general rule is that a mixture containing one of the five grains
>   (BROWS – barley, rye, oats, wheat, spelt) in cooked form is a
>   mezonos,even if the grain is only a minority ingredient

So, even in your case, with the barley being the minority ingredient, you would still say *mezonot*. However, the article continues:

> When the pieces of potato or meat are large enough so that they are
>   consumed individually without any grains, they require their own
>   brachos both before and after consumption.

I infer that since it mentions "potato", above, which is *adamah*, the rule should apply to beans which is also *adamah*.

In other words, if one were to eat the beans separately, and they are large pieces such that no barley would be on the forkful, then one neds a separate bracha of *admah* on the beans.

(FYI, this 2nd rule applies to all mixtures. Generally, one goes after the majority ingredient or "main" ingredient. However, if one intentionally eats each ingredient separately and enjoys each one separately, then, he must make separate brachot, despite the fact that it is a mixture. This scenario is quite common when eating a fruit "salad" that has mainly, e.g., assorted melons, but also some grapes and one eats and enjoys both separately. )

Comment: In my chulent i doubt it is ever possible to get a forkful without barley, and even if it was possible it is not the normal way of eating the chulent (since the barley is added for flavor), unlike the fruit salad where everything can be enjoyed separately, so i would say it is a mezonos.

Comment: @Bach I'd agree. However, it seems that if you were to intentionally pick out just beans (I'm not sure if you can do this without the melacha of "borer", but that's a separate discussion), and eat them, you would have to say *adamah* on the beans.